# mysql query with join repeats results

Tags: mysql, join

i have this query:

```
select distinct eventi.img as eventi,prodotti.img as prodotti
from eventi
JOIN prodotti WHERE eventi.homepage = prodotti.homepage
```

that returns this result:
[phpmyadmin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zqh.png)

As you can see, i have 3 events and it's ok, but i have only 1 product and it's repeated 3 times. How do i get the products result not repeated?
Even if it's possible to group all results in a single column.

Comment: and what do you want to see there? you want `prodotti` to be returned in only 1srt row? or in 2nd one? or 3rd? provide tables schema and expected result please. and stop using screenshots, insert that data as text in your post.

Comment: i want the unique result of prodotti added in the same column of events. so i have 1 column only  and the final result would be: events1.jpg, events2.jpg, events3.jpg, products1.jpg

Comment: so you want to get back 4 records in 1 column?

Comment: 4 or 10 or infinite records.  just all in 1 column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventi.img as img
FROM eventi
WHERE homepage = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT prodotti.img 
FROM prodotti 
WHERE homepage = 1
```

Comment: ok this does the trick but i need the part "WHERE eventi.homepage = prodotti.homepage" or "WHERE homepage = 1". Both "eventi" and "prodotti" tables have "homepage" field. I need to display results for homepage = 1 . How? Seems like i can't add WHERE clause to the query you wrote

Comment: awesome, thank you! how do i add this as final answer?